# How to remove first and last row in pandas dataframe using iloc

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

How can we remove first and last row in pandas `dataframe` using `iloc` method in one-Step something like `[[0:, :-1]]` , However if i only need to get the first and last row via `iloc` as below.

### DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)

header={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36", "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"}
url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/'
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

#read second table in url
df = pd.read_html(r.text)[1].iloc[[0, -1]]
#replace nan to zero
df = df[['Country,Other', 'TotalCases', 'NewCases', 'TotalDeaths', 'NewDeaths', 'TotalRecovered', 'ActiveCases', 'Serious,Critical']].replace(np.nan, "0")
print(df)
```

### Output:

Below i can get the first and last which i need to remove.

```
    Country,Other  TotalCases  NewCases  TotalDeaths NewDeaths  TotalRecovered  ActiveCases  Serious,Critical
0           World     2828826  +105,825     197099.0    +6,182        798371.0      1833356           58531.0
213        Total:     2828826  +105,825     197099.0    +6,182        798371.0      1833356           58531.0
```

However, I can remove the last row as `df = pd.read_html(r.text)[1].iloc[:-1]` , however there are other ways which i know as of now like below but those are again in  two steps.

```
df.drop(df.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
df.drop(df.head(1).index,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of dropping, you can use filtering:

```
df = pd.read_html(r.text)[1].iloc[1:-1]
```

This will get you every country from China to Yemen.

Comment: Excellent @Code Different, my bad i was using `.iloc[1:, -1]` ... thanks +1